# Retrieving data from embedded database wont work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, derby

I am trying to save data from my registration page to my database but it is not working some how. Does anyone have advise on how I can fix it?

This is my jsp page form. 
I am using an embedded derby database.
Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form class="form-signin"  method="POST" action="newuserservlet">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level"  name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level"  name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"> 
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Sign up</button>
```

This my servlet:

```
public class newuserservlet  extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastName");

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        String strUrl = "jdbc:derby:billsdb;create=true";
        dbConnection  = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl);
        PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("insert into USERDATA values(?,?)");
        stmt.setString(1, firstname);
        stmt.setString(2, lastname);
        int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            out.println("You are successfully registered.....");
        }
    } catch (Exception ey) {
        System.out.println(ey);
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: 1) What does _it is not working_ mean? Is there any exception printed? 2) Replace `System.out.println(ey);` with `ey.printStackTrace();` so you can see where the problem happens.

Comment: it just comes a blank page when i click the submit button , i changed it and nothing happened

Comment: Have you checked the console output and/or log file?

Comment: When you get that "blank page", do a "view source" in your browser, and see if there's anything in there which isn't displaying.

Comment: Have you mapped the URL "<urlOfYourFormPage>/newuserservlet" to your servlet? Because that's the URL that is invoked when you submit the form (because that's what is in the form's 'action' attribute).